# Get DIV width and height in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, size

I'm trying to get the div width and height as the user changes it and submit that number to another page.  I can't seem to figure out how to get the width and height though.

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $( "#set div" ).draggable({ 
    stack: "#set div",
    preventCollision: true,
    containment: $('#main_content'),
      stop: function(event, ui) {
          var mydiv = document.getElementById("set");
          var pos_x = ui.offset.left;
          var pos_y = ui.offset.top;

          var width = mydiv.style.width;        ----THIS DOESN'T WORK
          var height = mydiv.style.height;      ----THIS DOESN'T WORK

          var window_width = window.innerWidth;
          var window_height = window.innerHeight;
          var need = ui.helper.data("need");

          console.log(pos_x);
          console.log(pos_y);
          console.log(width);
          console.log(window_width);
          console.log(need);

          //Do the ajax call to the server
          $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "updatecoords.php",
              data: { x: pos_x, y: pos_y, need_id: need, width: width, height: height, window_width: window_width, window_height: window_height}
            }).done(function( msg ) {
              alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
            });  
      }
  });
});
</script>
```

What's the proper way to do this?

Comment: no, those lines of code work fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you're already using jQuery, you can just do:

```
var width;

if (need == 1) {
   width = $("#web").width();
} else {
   width = $("#set").width();
}
```

Comment: in my code I have a **var need**.  How would i tell the script that if **need** = 1, then var width= $("#web").width()

Comment: I've edited the answer to take into account the value of need.

Answer (score 24):

**It's quite wrong to use `ele.style.width` to get the element's width!!!!!!**

In native JavaScript, you can get a element's CSS through two ways:

### Standard Method

```
window.getComputedStyle(ele)
```

For example,

```
var ele = document.getElementById("content"), // Do not use #
    eleStyle = window.getComputedStyle(ele);
/* Below is the width of ele */
var eleWidth = eleStyle.width;
```

### IE(IE 8 And Before)

```
element.currentStyle
```

For example,

```
var ele = document.getElementById("content"), // Do not use #
    eleStyle = ele.currentStyle;
/* Below is the width of ele */
var eleWidth = eleStyle.width;
```

### Why Not Use `ele.style`?

`ele.style` is just get the attribule style of `ele`.  If you use `ele.style.width`, you just get the width of `ele.style`, not the real width of `ele`.

If you have done something like:

```
ele.style.width = "55px"
```

You get "55px" when using `ele.style.width`.  If you haven't, you will get undefined.

### How To Do In jQuery?

Use `$ele.width()` (if you want the "exact" width, use `$ele.outWidth()`), jQuery has done everything for you.

Answer (score 15):

In plain vanilla JavaScript use

```
var width = mydiv.offsetWidth;
var height = mydiv.offsetHeight;
```

This will give you numeric values, or

```
var width = mydiv.offsetWidth + 'px';
var height = mydiv.offsetHeight + 'px';
```

If you want them in "CSS" format.

Comment: For anyone wondering, `offsetWidth` is the faster of the two: https://jsperf.com/getcomputedstyle-vs-offsetwidth-offsetheight

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using jQuery, you'll probably want to know about the following:

$('#id').outerWidth()
$('#id').outerWidth(true)

These will come in very handy. This allows you to find the total width of the div (padding, border, width and (optional argument) margin).

http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/