# How get size of print area?

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

Need size area of print in pixels  for calculate content.
For size i use css:

```
@page {
   size: 11in 8.5in;
   margin: 1in;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little bit vague, but assuming you're trying to do this via JavaScript, see:

[How do I retrieve an HTML element's actual width and height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294250/how-do-i-retrieve-an-html-elements-actual-width-and-height)

[Get div height with plain JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15615552/get-div-height-with-plain-javascript)

[Get DIV width and height in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16471767/get-div-width-and-height-in-javascript)

Comment: No, I need size print area(on printing ctrl+p) for calculate content.